# Ektron blog post automatic email notification: URL to the post has pre production link

Tags: ektron

I am new to Ektron, and working on production issue.
**Scenario:** On every blog post, ektron sends an automatic email notification to all subscribed user. The email body has link to the new post. 
**Issue:** URL is pointing to pre-prod site. 
ie, Instead of www.mysite.com/blog/newpost it is preview.mysite.com/blog/newpost.
I did go through many links on the internet. Also digged ektron documentation. Found that it uses email variable like “@appContentTitle@” , "@appPostUrl@". Do we have an option to change the value of this variable?

Answer (score 0):

In work area settings there is an checkbox to say it is a staging server.